# LL(1) parse table

Tags: parsing

i have manually generated a LL(1) parse table for this non recursive grammar (please see the grammar below) but when i am trying to see if i have generated correct grammar using this online tool, it is not generating the parse table but there is no error message either. Can any one give me a clue please! thanks in advance

```
here is link for the tool:
http://andrewduncan.net/parsing/index.html

A  -> C B               
B  -> or C B |          
C  -> E D               
D  -> and E D |         
E  -> F | not F         
F  -> G | ( A )         
G  -> H I H             
H  -> string | number   
I  -> =  | >
```

Comment: There's information toward the bottom of the page you referenced.  You're not following the rules.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying.  I am not sure where it went wrong(may be something that I am not seeing.. but... same grammar works in another site ....   http://smlweb.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/start.html

Comment: That grammar is clearly recursive. Eg. `B -> or C B` (and various other productions).

Comment: is there any online tool that will convert this grammar to a non recursive one ?

Comment: Did you notice the requirement `Every production must have only one right-hand result. So  A ➝ B | c  must be rendered with two productions  A ➝ B  and  A`? Also the fact that you must use ε for an empty right-hand side.

Comment: @deb: It is not a problem that the grammar is recursive. A non-recursive grammar can only produce a finite number of strings, which would be quite a limitation. Perhaps you meant that the grammar is not *left*-recursive.

Comment: Hi, this was the original grammar i wrote boolean       -> bool_term | boolean OR bool_term  
bool_term     -> bool_factor | bool_term AND bool_factor
bool_factor   -> bool_primary | NOT bool_primary
bool_primary  -> predicate | ( boolean )  
predicate     -> expr comp_op expr 
expr          -> string | number.
comp_op       -> = |  >